# Filter any number in list or any string in list with python without using another list

Tags: python

I have a list, for example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 'a', 'b']
```

I can filter out the numbers or strings if I use another list.
I am trying to make the function more flexible by detecting any string or number but I am not able to find the approach to it. Can someone tell me the best approach to the problem?

This is the code I have, which is working for me:

```
l = [1, 2, 'a', 'b']
def filter_list(l):
  actual_list = [1, 2]
  list_filter = []
  for w in l:
      if w in actual_list:
          list_filter.append(w)     
  return list_filter
```

I want to do the same without relying on `actual_list = [1, 2]` and which can be applied to either strings or numbers.

Comment: can you add a a minimal reproducible example of what you have tried

Comment: any input output example ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read this [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using filter here.
Filter is designed for exactly this use case here, .i.e, to filter some thing from a composite object.

`filter(lambda x: type(x) == int or type(x) == float, your_list)`

For more info about filter, read here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filter-in-python

Answer (score 1):

I understood your question like this:

I have the list [1, 2,'a','b'] and want to filter either for numbers or for strings without relaying on another list which contains the elements to be deleted, such as: `[x for x in lst if x not in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]`

Therefore a possible answer would be:

```
lst = [1, 2,'a','b', 3.0]

# if you want only the numbers you could check the type of each element
lst_numbers = [x for x in lst if type(x).__name__ == "int" or type(x).__name__ == 'float']

 # if you want only the strings you could check the type of each element
lst_strings = [x for x in lst if type(x).__name__ == "str"]
```

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding!